# custom function with "indexpath"

Tags: iphone, ios, function, uitableview

I have a problem with my method when I took the code from -[MyController tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:] and put it inside my function submitAll.

```
-(void)submitAll: (id)sender
{
    NSArray *data_webs;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) { "problem here"
        data_webs = [mcq_question data_webs];
    } else {
        data_webs = [structured_question data_webs];
    }

    data_web *current_data ;

    current_data = [data_webs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; "problem here"
    NSString *is_submited = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[current_data content_2]];

    NSLog(@"%@", [current_data the_id]);
}
```

- what is the equivalent value for indexPath.row in custom function?
- what is the right script inside if (indexPath.section == 0)?
- my purpose for this function is to list all the value inside [current_data the_id] or put in array and refresh the page.
- I am not sure if I am following the right way here, I am just a newbie in IOS.

Comment: When is `submitAll` called? What is the `sender`?

Comment: What is submitAll used for? I'd guess from the syntax its an action method on a button, but that's not clear. What are you intending to do with it?

Comment: Hi, SubmitAll is a button/action. When I click submit it should display the data on data_webs and refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you are calling your submit all method. But try it like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
      [self submitAll:[indexPath row]]

}

-(void)submitAll:(NSInteger) row
{
    NSArray *data_webs;

    if (row == 0) 
   { 
      data_webs = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[mcq_question data_webs]];
      //Assuming [mcq_question data_webs] retuns NSArray
   }
   else 
   {
        data_webs = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[structured_question data_webs]];
    }

    data_web *current_data ;

    current_data = [data_webs objectAtIndex:row]; "problem here"
    NSString *is_submited = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[current_data content_2]];

     NSLog(@"%@", [current_data the_id]);
}
```

Comment: If I am not going to click the submitAll button, then your script is working. But I need to click the button before the script run.

Comment: So if it get this right, you need this method -(void) submitAll to be executed when you click a button?. Is this button is placed in a UITableviewcell?

Comment: If each tableview cell is going to have a button and if -(void) submitall method is to be executed on click of that button, one way of achieving it is assign a tag number to the buttons. For example, for your button in row 0 assign tag 0 and row1 assign tag 1.It's something like [mybutton setTag:[indexpath row]] in your - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method

Comment: Now in -(void)submitAll: (id)sender { if([sender tag] == 0) } will pass in your cell row to submitall method

Comment: Yes I need -(void) submitAll to be executed when I click the button , But the button is not placed inside the tableview. This button is only one. Its like when I press the button submitAll, all the data id inside the table will be displayed in NSlog.

Comment: In that case, you cannot use indexPath. You need to consolidate your data directly from your data source. indexPath can be determined only when a user interacts with UITableview and since here user interacts with button indexpath should not be used.Could you tell me why are you checking indexPath.section == 0 in your code?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, to be honest I was just testing the script. I have data_webs = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[mcq_question data_webs]]; and data_webs = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[structure_question data_webs]]; and I want to display all the ID inside mcq_question and structure_question.

Comment: I was trying to display the ID for mcq_question and structure_question. Do you have any suggestion to display all the ID?

Comment: for (id obj in [mcq_question data_webs]) {NSLog(@"%@",obj)} will log all objects inside NSAarray. Do the same thing for [structure_question data_webs]